# Format for passing a numerically indexed array in a get request

Tags: arrays, http, get

I know that the standard method for passing named parameters in a get request, is:

```
?paramName=value&anotherParam=anotherValue...
```

In my case, I want to pass an array of parameters
However, I want to pass multiple parameters with the same meaning - an array. 
In js that would be

```
 var users = ['bob', 'sam', 'bill'];
```

and I want to pass the users array via get.

What would be the way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to serialize them into some form of string that can be re-parsed into an array.

For, example, you could use...

```
?param[]=a&param[]=b&param[]=c
```

...or something like...

```
?params=[a][b][b].
```

Comment: At the meanwhile I figured out that the first is the php standard way to encode an array